# Prove/Disprove: $A - \lfloor A/B \rfloor - \lceil A/B \rceil \leq \lfloor A/B \rfloor \times (B+1)$ for $A \geq B$

Tags: inequality

For $A \geq B$, both are strictly positive integers, is the following true?
$$A - \lfloor A/B \rfloor - \lceil A/B \rceil \leq \lfloor A/B \rfloor \times (B+1)$$

I tried the technique used in proving a very similar question:
[Prove/Disprove: $A - \lfloor A/B \rfloor - \lceil A/B \rceil \leq (\lfloor A/B \rfloor + 1) \times B$ for $A \geq B$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3797302/prove-disprove-a-lfloor-a-b-rfloor-lceil-a-b-rceil-leq-lfloor-a-b)

But it seems like it didn't work in proving this. I also tried empirically generating random A and B's, but also can't find a counterexample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{f}[1]{\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor}$
Let $B = 100$ and $A = 199$. Then:
\begin{align*}
LHS &= 199 - 1 - 2 = 196 \\
RHS &= 1(100 + 1) = 101
\end{align*}
So the inequality is false.

---

**EDIT**: In response to OP's comment, suppose we restrict further that $\f{A/B} \geq N$ for some $N \in \Bbb{Z}^+$. Let $B = 3N + 3$, and let $A = (N + 1)(3N + 3) - 1$. Clearly $A \geq B$ and $\f{A/B} = N$.
\begin{align*}
LHS &= (N + 1)(3N + 3) - 1 - N - (N + 1) \\
&= (N + 1)(3N + 1) \\
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
RHS &= N(3N + 4) \\
&= N(3N + 1) + 3N \\
&= (N + 1)(3N + 1) - (3N + 1) + 3N \\
&= (N + 1)(3N + 1) - 1 < LHS
\end{align*}
So the inequality will still fail.

Comment: Oh! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just curious, will it hold if $\lfloor A/B \rfloor \geq 2$?

Comment: What about the correctness of this version of the question? $$A - \lfloor A/B \rfloor - \lceil A/B \rceil \leq \lfloor A/B \rfloor \times (A+1)$$ Thanks in advance

Comment: @Nicholas see my edited answer.

Comment: @user0410 I believe it's more appropriate to post that as a new question instead of commenting here.

Comment: You know, I think it is not appropriate to post similar questions in SE especially when the base idea has been introduced by another OP. Therefore, maybe it is a suitable suggestion that please post another answer in this page and then kindly add more details about the comment. I appreciate you taking the time to answer our questions.

Comment: @user0410 I get your point, but two questions being of a similar idea does not mean that they should be discussed in the same thread on stackexchange (since, in your case, they are still technically different questions). I suggest you credit the OP in your new question by linking to this thread, and I'll be happy to post an answer there after I think about it.

Comment: Although I have bad experiences about these suggestions in SE (changed my username after five years and created user 0410), ok I will post a new questions. Thanks again.

Comment: @user0410 I appreciate your understanding.

Comment: Hi Clement, I've a follow-up question on this same question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3797474/how-does-a-relate-to-b-if-a-lfloor-a-b-rfloor-lceil-a-b-rceil-leq was wondering if you have any insights on it.