# Proof or Counterexample for $A - \lfloor A/B \rfloor - \lceil A/B \rceil \leq \lfloor A/B \rfloor \times (A+1)$

Tags: inequality

Motivated by [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3797351/prove-disprove-a-lfloor-a-b-rfloor-lceil-a-b-rceil-leq-lfloor-a-b-r/3797360?noredirect=1#comment7823689_3797360) and specially suggested by @Clement Yung:

Let $A$ and $B$ are strictly positive integers such that $A \geq B$.

*Question:* How to prove or make a counterexample for the following statement.

$$
\boxed{A - \lfloor A/B \rfloor - \lceil A/B \rceil \leq \lfloor A/B \rfloor \times (A+1)}
$$
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$\left\lfloor\frac AB\right\rfloor=k\ge1.$$

Then

$$A-k-\left\lceil\frac AB\right\rceil\le A-2k\le k(A+1).$$
is certainly true.

Comment: Now, it's clear. Thanks